# Restart make target from failure point

Tags: makefile

Is there a way to restart a make target from the point it failed at before? Or perhaps some other technology that can achieve this?

If `make testtarget` failed at the line `command b`

```
testtarget:
  command a
  command b
  command c
```

I would like to be able to run command b manually with whatever changes are necessary, then run `make testtarget --resume` or something like that.

Comment: Do you have any file produced by `command a`? If no I think there is no solution. If yes you should seperate `command a` from `testtarget`.

Comment: @uzsolt even if `command a` doesn't produce any file, it could be replaced vith `command a && touch command_a` and separated from `testtarget`

Comment: @ComeRaczy: ah, yes, it's a good idea :) Write it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you separate commands from recipe of `testtarget` target into separate recipes. Something like this:

```
# Separate recipe of 'testtarget' target into sub targets and order them.
testtarget: testtarget_a testtarget_b testtarget_c
testtarget_c:|testtarget_b
testtarget_b:|testtarget_a

testtarget_a:; command a
testtarget_b:; command b || $(MAKE) testtarget_b_failed
testtarget_c:; command c

# Add commands to recipe of this target to fix failure of "command b"
testtarget_b_failed:; 

.PHONY: testtarget_b_failed testtarget testtarget_a testtarget_b testtarget_c
```